# GeoNodes: How to use captured positions from one set of points and offset individual mesh island positions using the captured positions

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, geometry

Link to the blend file (uses Blender 4.0): [image]

My question is a little long, but hopefully with the screenshots it becomes clear what I am trying to achieve.

Here's what I have so far in my geometry nodes setup: [image]

The aim is to produce packed biological cells (neural stem cells) that have a particular elongated shape (this is how stem cells are packed in the developing brain and spinal cord). Currently I am able to produce cells where the cell body (the bulge in the image below) is determined randomly like so:
[image]

Now what i would like to do next is animate the positions of the bulges to move up and down in the z-direction. Specifically I would like to do this based on the positions of another set of instanced points, because I have some other geometry node setup that produces nicely packed points that have collision detection when they move, which lookes like this:
[image]

My question then is if I implement this collision detection to define the positions of instances, how would I use these positions to determine the z-offset, instead of using the random offsets that I am using now. I have tried using capture attributes on the positions in order to use them, but I am a little stumped on how to apply them successfully to the node tree I have shown here.

Here’s a summary of what I want to achieve with this:

[image]

Here it is only the bulges that should move up and down, not the entire cells. The collision detection could be tricky in the sense that the collisions will have some movement in the x/y-direction, and I would need to come up with a solution to deal with that later, but the main thing is first figuring out how to make the bulges move, ideally by mapping their movement onto a collision detection algorithm.

I am fairly new to blender and geometry nodes, so forgive me if I have done this in an odd way! I would really appreaciate the help as I am really stuck on how to do this/unsure of whether it is possible.

Comment: Hi Joshua, you want help for free from us in our spare time - which is ok, but don't you think you should it make then as easy as possible to help you? If yes, pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually. thx.

Comment: Just to clarify;  you want the bulges to move? And move in a way that avoids collision? A straightforward description / sketch of the desired **end**-product would help here, I think

Comment: @Chris Hi Chris, thanks for pointing that out, I have attached the blend file at the top of the post. Many thanks!

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi Robin, thanks for the suggestion, I have added a sketch at the end of the post to clarify.

Comment: @Joshua thanks for the work you've put into this! That's much clearer.